# open dialog by condition

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I want to make a dialog that get opened only if a condition occurs.

In the dialog, I will have `ok` and `cancel` buttons, and I want to continue only if the user presses `OK`.

I.e.

```
if (condition)
{
 open dialog.
 if user clicked OK, do something
 else do something else
}
```

How can I do it using [mfc](/questions/tagged/mfc)?

Comment: Check out [`AfxMessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of CDIalog::DoModal(). It will return a value IDOK, if user clicked OK and IDCANCEL, if user clicked Cancel.

Check this page in MSDN. [CDialog::DoModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)